# SimpleInterest and Percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

**A Man invested 1/3 of his capital at 7% , 1/4 at 8% and the Remainder at 10% If his Annual Income is Rs 561 and the Capital is**

I have Tried:

```
**Total Percentage = 25%
 let the Capital be x, 1/3 of x at 7 %, 1/4 of X at 8%, Remainder of x at 10%
first Si + second Si + Third si = 561
(x/3*1*7)/100 + (x/4*1*8)/100 + remainder at 10% =561
How to Calculate the Value of x, how i will take the Remainder Value, I have Strucked**
```

Comment: remainder value = $x-\left(\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{3}x\right)$

Comment: @MathBot My Logic is Correct ah?

Comment: Yes I think that your logic is correct .

Comment: @MathBot Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked several questions during your first days on this site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).